# Launching Applications In Fullscreen From Terminal in OSX 10.9 Mavericks

Tags: macos, tmux, fullscreen

It's my first venture into the world of tmux, and the end goal is an executable script that directly starts tmux (instead of launching Terminal and then starting up tmux from there) in fullscreen mode so that it immediately occupies a new workspace under the new Mavericks release. Currently, the script will launch tmux with my configurations just fine, but then I have to click on the icon in the top right of the window to enter fullscreen mode and thus isolate tmux in its own workspace. Does anybody know of a line (or several lines) that could be inserted into the script to automatically fullscreen the tmux session whenever I launch it?

Answer (score 0):

If the application has a shortcut for going into fullscreen mode you could let the script "press" that shortcut.

For example: After application is started wait 2 seconds and then press ^⌘F

```
sleep 2
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to keystroke "f" using {control down, command down}'
```

Don't know if there's a more elegant way of doing it